# How do i extract text from pdf stored on blob storage using itext7?

Tags: c#, azure, itext7, azure-blob-storage

i'm using itext7 to extract text from pdf . Here is my code to extract the text for local pdf file :

```
 var pageText = new StringBuilder();  
    using(PdfDocument pdfDocument = new PdfDocument(new PdfReader("E:\\es.pdf"))) {  
        var pageNumbers = pdfDocument.GetNumberOfPages();  
        for (int i = 1; i <= pageNumbers; i++) {  
            LocationTextExtractionStrategy strategy = new LocationTextExtractionStrategy();  
            PdfCanvasProcessor parser = new PdfCanvasProcessor(strategy);  
            parser.ProcessPageContent(pdfDocument.GetFirstPage());  
            pageText.Append(strategy.GetResultantText());  
        }  
    }
```

But,i'm not getting how can i parse pdf stored on azure blob storage.

Comment: as exactly I thought while reading your question, somehow you would need to convert the byte/blob to file-stream and then to could go into the desired extension. on the other hand, if you are using .net MVC  here "https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/blogs/uploaddownloaddelete-a-file-file-stream-in-azure-blob-storage-c-sharpnet " you would find a perfect example.

Comment: Do you have any other concerns? If you have no other concerns, could you please accept it as an answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to read pdf form azure blob, please refer to the following code

```
 string storageAccountName = "andyprivate";
            string accountKey = "";
            var blobServiceClient = new BlobServiceClient(
                new Uri($"https://{storageAccountName}.blob.core.windows.net"),
                new StorageSharedKeyCredential(storageAccountName, accountKey),
                new BlobClientOptions());

            var containerClient = blobServiceClient.GetBlobContainerClient("test");
            var blob = containerClient.GetBlobClient("sample.pdf");
            BlobProperties properties = await blob.GetPropertiesAsync();
            var pageText = new StringBuilder();
            using (var stream = await blob.OpenReadAsync(position: 0, bufferSize: (int)properties.ContentLength))
            using (PdfDocument pdfDocument = new PdfDocument(new PdfReader(stream))) {
                var pageNumbers = pdfDocument.GetNumberOfPages();
                for (int i = 1; i <= pageNumbers; i++)
                {
                    LocationTextExtractionStrategy strategy = new LocationTextExtractionStrategy();
                    PdfCanvasProcessor parser = new PdfCanvasProcessor(strategy);
                    parser.ProcessPageContent(pdfDocument.GetPage(i));
                    pageText.Append(strategy.GetResultantText());
                    pageText.Append(Environment.NewLine);


                }

                Console.WriteLine(pageText);
            }
```

[image]